# Fixed array and random numbers in an SQL query

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server-2008, random

What's the easiest way to select one of five fixed strings returned in an SQL Server query, randomly?

I.e. the equivalent of:

```
function randomColumn() {
   var values = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'cherry', 'lemon'];
   var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
   return values[idx];
}
```

I need to change my existing SQL script to have a certain column return one of these values, without the need to change my client code.

Do I need to create a temp table?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I think you may want to adjust the upper bound of your random numbers - your set of values is 5 elements long.

Comment: @X-Zero: I wrote it as a JavaScript example (which uses [zero-based indexing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm)), so I did this automatically, without too much thought. Yes, `Math.floor` along with `5` would work best. But I think it shows the basic intent anyway.

Comment: Sorry, kicking myself somewhat because I was reading the `Math.round()` as `Math.floor()` (a round-down).  Of course, assuming the distribution of values resulting from the multiplication with the random double is even, your endpoints (0, 4) _would_ have been about half as probable as any of the other elements in the list.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I realized when I read your comment too. Note to self: start eating healthier, take regular exercise, and take distribution into account whenever you round random values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a temporary table for a few strings, you can create the result on the fly:

```
select str
from (
  select 0 as id, 'apple' as str
  union all
  select 1, 'banana'
  union all
  select 2, 'orange'
  union all
  select 3, 'cherry'
  union all
  select 4, 'lemon'
) x
where id = floor(rand() * 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select top 1 Value
from Table1
order by newid()
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9250/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 'apple' values 
INTO #tmp
UNION ALL 
Select'banana' values 
UNION ALL 
Select 'orange' values      
.
.
.  
select top 1 values 
from #tmp
order by newid()
```

**OR**

```
ALTER TABLE #tmp
ADD id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)
DECLARE @rand BIGINT 

SET @rand=rand()*4

select top 1 values 
from #tmp
where id=@rand
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ListofIDs TABLE(IDs VARCHAR(100), ID INT IDENTITY(1,1));
INSERT INTO @ListofIDs
SELECT 'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT '20'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'c'
UNION ALL
SELECT '30'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'd';
SELECT * FROM @ListofIDs;

SELECT  Ids from @ListofIDs where ID=1+ CONVERT(INT, (5)*RAND())
```